# How to authorize a Blazor WebAssembly SPA app using Identity Server

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am writing a demo Blazor WebAssembly SPA technical demo app, but I have some problems with authentication.
I'm going to use Identity Server to do the authorization but i can't find any libraries to support it.
All the tutorials I found guided to use Blazor Server or add an ASP.net Core hosted, but it's not really make sense for my demo app.

I am glad if anyone can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## March 12th, 2020

To add OIDC to an existing Blazor WASM app using an existing OAuth identity provider read [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with the Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
The new [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/3.2.0-preview2.20160.5) support automatic silent renew.

If you prefere to use a configuration file instead of hard coded values, you can setup the app like this

> Visit [theidserver.herokuapp.com/](https://theidserver.herokuapp.com/) for a full fonctional sample.

- **Upgrade your app to 3.2.0 Preview 2**
  Read [Upgrade an existing project paragraph](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/)
- **Add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication**

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication::3.2.0-preview2.20160.5
```

- **Add AuthenticationService.js to index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
...
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- **Add an oidc.json file in application's wwwroot folder with this structure**

```
{
  "authority": "https://myidp.com", // Uri to your IDP server
  "client_id": "myclientid", // Your client id
  "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44333/authentication/login-callback", // Uri to the application login callback
  "post_logout_redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44333/authentication/logout-callback", // Uri to the application logout callback
  "response_type": "code", // OAuth flow response type. For `authorization_code` flow the response type is 'code'. For `implicit` flow, the response type is 'id_token token'
  "scope": "BlazorIdentityServer.ServerAPI openid profile" // list of scope your application wants
}
```

- **Configure Api authorization to read config from your oidc.json file**
  Update your *Program.cs* to be :

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorIdentityServer.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddBaseAddressHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options => options.ProviderOptions.ConfigurationEndpoint = "oidc.json");

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

## March 11th, 2020

[3.2.0-preview2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/) provides a way to use Blazor Wasm with IdentityServer
Read

- [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly hosted app with Identity Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly additional security scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#save-app-state-before-an-authentication-operation)

## March 9th, 2020

At the moment there are some blazor OIDC lib you can use but none are certified and implement all features.

- [HLSoft.BlazorWebAssembly.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://github.com/sounj142/HLSoft.BlazorWebAssembly.Authentication.OpenIdConnect)
- [Authfix/Blazor-Oidc](https://github.com/Authfix/Blazor-Oidc)
- [sotsera/sotsera.blazor.oidc](https://github.com/sotsera/sotsera.blazor.oidc)
- [MV10/BlazorOIDC](https://github.com/MV10/BlazorOIDC/tree/master/ClientSite)

If you are curious, I write [my own](https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/tree/master/src/Blazor/Aguacongas.Blazor.Oidc) to support token silent renew but it's not finished yet and I stuck by this issue : [[wasm] WasmHttpMessageHandler, Provide fetch options per message](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/17808).
The issue is fixed in this [not yet merged PR](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/17932). So have to wait or implement my own `WasmHttpMessageHandler`.

A second approach is to wrap [oidc.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) using [JS interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know these projects. You helped me a lot.
I just played around with these repositories and I think HLSoft.BlazorWebAssembly.Authentication.OpenIdConnect is suitable with my app. 
The author has just written it recently, it will support neswest blazor, and he supplied many expamles, one for full-website authentication, and one has silent renew token supporting.
I think it's enough for my project - only technical review demo though.
Again, thank you very much :D

Comment: Thanks, just finished the demo ^^. I'll check that new Microsoft's feature

Comment: Any recommendation on how to get a full SPA login instead of using the MVC scaffolding?

Comment: @Insight I hope this like will help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-authentication-user-interface