# How to integrate Razor Components (Blazor WASM Prerendered) with ASP.Net Core MVC Views Authentication (OpenId Connect)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, web-component, blazor-webassembly

All the articles I found cover Blazor WASM integration with existing ASP.Net Core MVC views (through component tag) only. I could not find anything about authentication or how to pass OpenId Connect token from the view to the embedded Blazor component. Can anyone show me a good resource that cover this subject in details?

Comment: Do you want this kind of integration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593985/how-to-authorize-a-blazor-webassembly-spa-app-using-identity-server

Comment: Nope. My case is totally different. Blazor would run as a component within MVC's view itself and pre-rendered as WebAssembly.